# Is there a way to get user's email address via API?

Tags: bitbucket-api

Is there a way via BitBucket's API to get the user's email address associated with our group?
Under:

```
https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/users/foobar
```

I see their username, display_name, first_name, last_name, etc., but no email address.

In a nutshell, I'm trying to figure out if anyone in our team is NOT using our company's email address.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's an [`emails`](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/emails+Resource#emailsResource-GETalistofuser'semailaddresses) endpoint:

> Gets the email addresses associated with the account. This call requires authentication.

In your case that would be:

```
https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/users/foobar/emails
```

Comment: I am also having a similar situation. From this I am only getting the email addresses associated with the account.But I want the email of each users in the individual repositories under that account

Comment: I also need the same. Did you figure it out? I want the all listed email addresses.

Comment: There is an active feature request for the same. Please upvote for prioritization.

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-13143